# How to unwind an object based on deeply nested list fields in scala?

Tags: java, scala, functional-programming

### Simplified Scenario

Lets take a simplified example with `2 levels` of nested fields in a case class.

Suppose I have a `case class` Person as shown below:

```
case class Address(
  name: String,
  zipCodes: List[String]
)

case class Person(
  name: String,
  address: List[Address]
)
```

Suppose I have an `object` for the above Person class as shown below:

```
val person1: Person = Person(
    name = "John",
    address = List(
      Address(
        name = "Address A",
        zipCodes = List("123","345")
      ),
      Address(
        name = "Address B",
        zipCodes = List("456","678")
      )
    )
  )
```

Now, I want to `unwind` this object `person1` in such a way that I get following flattened list of tuples:

```
List(    
    (John, Address A, 123)
    (John, Address A, 345)
    (John, Address B, 456)
    (John, Address B, 678)
)
```

Now, in this simple scenario, what I could do to unwind is as follow:

```
person1.address.flatMap{
    address => address.zipCodes.map{
      zipCode =>
        (person1.name, address.name, zipCode)
    }
```

### Question

In my real scenario, I can have `n levels` of nesting in the case class. So, it's not feasible for me to write n lines of flatMaps for each inner nested field to produce such tuple. Is there a generic(*if possible*), better, shorter yet functional way to achieve this in scala ?

Comment: You can use the syntax sugar of [**for comprehensions**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html) which is basically just a [nicer way to write those`flatMaps`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can write your example code using `for`:

```
for {
  address <- person1.address
  zipCode <- address.zipCodes
} yield {
  (person1.name, address.name, zipCode)
}
```

With this version it is easy to add as many levels of nesting as are required.

Another option is to give each nested class a `flat` method that creates the flattened version of the class using the `flat` method of the contained classes. This means that calling code does not need to know the nested structure, it just calls `flat` on the outer object. Or a typeclass could used if you can't change the original classes.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems contradictory – on the one hand, you're saying that you can have `n` levels of nesting (where `n` is presumably not known at compile time), and you therefore can't write `n` levels of `flatMap`s. But on the other hand you're saying you want to return a tuple – but the length of the tuple in your example corresponds to the depth of nesting, meaning that `n` is the same as the length of the tuple and thus a compile-time constant.

Anyway, if you need arbitrary degrees of nesting, you need to use recursion.

```scala
case class RoseTree[A](
  a: A,
  children: List[RoseTree[A]]
)

def unnest[A](tree: RoseTree[A]): List[List[A]] =
  tree match {
    case RoseTree(a, Nil) =>
      List(List(a))
    case RoseTree(a, children) =>
      children.flatMap(x => unnest(x).map(a :: _))
  }

val example = 
  RoseTree("John", List(
    RoseTree("Address A", List(
      RoseTree("123", Nil),
      RoseTree("345", Nil))),
    RoseTree("Address B", List(
      RoseTree("456", Nil),
      RoseTree("678", Nil))))

assert(unnest(example) == List(
  List("John", "Address A", "123"),
  List("John", "Address A", "345"),
  List("John", "Address B", "456"),
  List("John", "Address B", "678")))
```